# validations failing as blank when fields not blank

Tags: validation

I am runnning ruby 1.9.3 and rails 4.1.4
trying the following validations
in the models\profile.rb

```
attr_accessor :password
validates :name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :length => { :in => 3..20 }
validates :password, :confirmation => true #password_confirmation attr
```

validates_length_of :password, :in => 6..20, :on => :create
   before_save :encrypt_password

in view profiles\new.html.erb
from the form

```
<p>
<%= f.label :name %><br />
<%= f.text_field :name %>
</p>

<p>
  <%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :email %>
</p>

<p>
  <%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.label :interests %><br />
  <%= f.text_area :interests %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.label :zip %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :zip %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.label :country %><br />
  <%= f.country_select :country, ["United Kingdom"] %>  </p>
```

using strong parameters controllers\profile_controller,rb

```
 class ProfilesController < ApplicationController

def new
  @profile = Profile.new 
end
def create
  @profile = Profile.new(params[profile_params])
  if @profile.save
    flash[:notice] = "You signed up successfully"
    flash[:color]= "valid"
  else
    flash[:notice] = "Form is invalid"
    flash[:color]= "invalid"
  end
  render "new"
end
private
  ## Strong Parameters 
   def profile_params
     params.require(:profile).permit(:name, :email, :password, :interests,:zip)
  end
 end
```

validations always fail saying fields are blank. By causing an exception the report shows model profile with its fields populated. It is as if the data is simply not accessible so I suspect I'm misuing strong parameters sonehow.
Any opinions welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `profile_params` function is going to return a hash for you with the data directly.

What that basically does is it filters the `params` hash for the 'profile' key's value for the keys named as the parameters of `permit(...)`
So the way to fix is to write

```
@profile = Profile.new(profile_params)
```

instead of

```
@profile = Profile.new(params[profile_params])
```

With strong parameters you almost never interact with the `params` array directly from controller actions (such as `create`). The private strong parameter methods will handle that for you and by that, only safe, filtered data will be given to your controller actions.

Comment: Terrific, works fine. Thanks for your help and the education.

Comment: Sure would. How do I do that?